# Get the size of a repository over SSH or SFTP in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssh

**How can I get the size of a repository on an other host (with Net::SSH or Net::SFTP) in Ruby?**

By the size of a repository, I mean the sum of all the files in this repository, recursively.

I'd like to use this information to make sure the repository is smaller than a certain size. Then, if it is, I want to `tar` and download it.

Comment: I am afraid there is no API available in SSH for this usage. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4251.txt  However, if you are running linux on the ssh server side, you can use "du -msh" to get the total size of a certain directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation using the `ssh` gem:

```
require 'ssh'
s = SSH.new "example.com"
size = s.run "du -s /home/user | awk '{print $1}'" 
puts size
```

Implementation using `Net::SSH`:

```
require 'net/ssh'
s = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password)
size = s.exec!("du -s /home/user | awk '{print $1}'")
puts size
```

If your directory might have hidden items, then you can use a directory glob, or more-powerful more-flexible `find` command like this:

```
find /home/user -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec du -s {} + | 
awk '{sum = sum + $1}END{print sum}'
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this line to get the size in bytes: `size = ssh.exec!("du -sb #{path} | cut -f1")`

Comment: Good, glad to know it works. Yes, `cut` and `awk` are equivalent for the typical use. For the more powerful use, `awk` is handy because it can sum easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can proceed like this:

```
SPECIFIC_SIZE = 100
Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :password => "password") do |ssh|
  output = ssh.exec!("find /path/to/dir -type f | wc -l")
  if output.to_i > SPECIFIC_SIZE
    ssh.exec!("tar czf somedir.tar /path/to/dir") #your terminal tar command
  end
end
```